# spring boot using 2 different oauth providers at the same time

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, spring-security-oauth2

I'm facing a use where I have to check oauth token against 2 different oauth provider given an input context (private call to may api vs public call)

Is there a simple way to define 2 oauth provider in spring boot and how to configure this balancing between the 2 providers ?

Comment: Are you looking for registering multiple authentication providers on client app?

Comment: @S.Step I'm trying to plug my API to two different auth provider (keycloak in my case)

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to implement 2 `AuthenticationProvider` then in your configuration class that implements `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` you would autowire those providers. Finally override the `public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {` to add those providers.

```
@Configuration
public class SampleAuthConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider1 provider1;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider2 provider2;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
            .authenticationProvider(this.provider1)
            .authenticationProvider(this.provider2);
    }
}
```

Below are some tutorials. The may be outdated but may help you to figure it out.
https://dzone.com/articles/spring-security-authentication

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-auth-providers